# CMake target_sources and install

Tags: cmake

I am having a hard time figuring out how to install `PUBLIC` headers specified in [`target_sources()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/command/target_sources.html).

It appears that `target_sources()` is somewhat of a mystery for anything other than adding private sources to an executable.
After reading a lot of material, where especially [this blog entry](https://crascit.com/2016/01/31/enhanced-source-file-handling-with-target_sources/) was helpful, I managed to understand & bypass the issue with `target_sources()` and PUBLIC files. A `CMakeLists.txt` in one of the many subdirectories of my C++ library project looks like this:

```
target_sources(mylib
    PRIVATE
        foo.cpp

    PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/foo.hpp>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:foo.hpp>
)
```

This allows me to successfully build the library. However, upon installation, the header file(s) listed in the `PUBLIC` section of `target_sources()` are never installed.

My installation looks like this:

```
install(
    TARGETS
        mylib
    EXPORT mylib-targets
    LIBRARY
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        COMPONENT lib
    ARCHIVE
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        COMPONENT lib
    RUNTIME
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
        COMPONENT bin
    INCLUDES
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/mylib
```

However, this doesn't install any of the headers.
This [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56559641/1414496) mentions the use of [`PUBLIC_HEADER`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/prop_tgt/PUBLIC_HEADER.html) but reading the documentation doesn't give me the feeling that that is relevant in my case.

**Question:** What is the proper way of installing `PUBLIC` or `INTERFACE` headers using `install()`?

**Background:** My goal is to have a separate `CMakeLists.txt` in every subdirectory of my source tree. Each of these lists is supposed to use `target_sources()` to add `PRIVATE` and `PUBLIC` files to the build. All `PUBLIC` (and `INTERFACE`) sources should be installed during installation.

Comment: So did you end up adding  `set_target_properties` and `target_sources` to each of your subdirectories `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: Yes. Everything is now done using the various `target()` functions in the subdirectories.
However, public headers are added to a list named `HEADERS_PUBLIC`, which is then passed to `target_sources()` but also to the corresponding installation directive.
I can publish a blog post on this with a skeleton if that would help you out. Might take a few days tho.

Comment: No, that's alright. Thanks for the offer though. I believe I have it working now; although I'm not using the `install` command within the subdirectories `CMakeLists.txt` (which from your comment it sounds like that's what you're doing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PUBLIC` section of `target_sources` command has **nothing common** with *public headers* installed with `PUBLIC_HEADER` option of `install` command.

The headers you want to treat as *public* for your library should be listed in [PUBLIC_HEADER](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/prop_tgt/PUBLIC_HEADER.html) property for the target.

Documentation for [install(TARGETS)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/command/install.html#installing-targets) has a nice example of setting and installing private headers. In your case this would be:

```
# This defines `foo.hpp` located in the current source directory as a 'public header'.
set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER foo.hpp)
# This install public headers among with the library.
install(
  TARGETS
    mylib
  PUBLIC_HEADER
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/mylib
  # ... other options
)
```

See also that related question: [How to configure CMakeLists.txt to install public headers of a shared library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54271925/how-to-configure-cmakelists-txt-to-install-public-headers-of-a-shared-library).

---

Note also, that `INCLUDES` and `PUBLIC_HEADERS` clauses for `install(TARGETS)` command are **different** things:

- `INCLUDES` specifies include directory for the installed library
- `PUBLIC_HEADERS` specifies directory where all target's public headers will be copied upon installation.

E.g. if you want your header file to be used via

```
#include <mylib/foo.h>
```

then you need provide following options for `install()` command:

```
  PUBLIC_HEADER
    # The header will be places at ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/mylib/foo.h
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/mylib
  INCLUDES
    # This directory will be used as include directory.
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
```

So `<include-directory>` joined (via `/`) with the **relative path** in `#include<>` directive will give **absolute path** to the header file.

Comment: The `PUBLIC_HEADER` documentation always gives me the sensation that this is a macOS/iOS only feature. Given your post I assume that this is incorrect?

Comment: I would interpret this property as: "This property is **intended** for macOS/iOS, but is **usable** for other platforms too". See the phrase "On non-Apple platforms these headers may be installed using the `PUBLIC_HEADER` option to the `install(TARGETS)` command." at the end of the description of this property in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/prop_tgt/PUBLIC_HEADER.html).

Comment: My verdict after all of this is: `target_sources()` has absolutely no effect when using `install(TARGETS)`. Therefore, when trying to have a separate `CMakeLists.txt` in each of my library's sub-directories, I just use the "old" method of adding each source file's path (relative to the top-level `CMakeLists.txt`) to a variable (list) and then use `install(FILES)`. Is that correct?
All I was looking for is a way of having a `CMakeLists.txt` in each sub-directory listing that directory's source files relatively to that `CMakeLists.txt` while preserving the directory structure when installing.

Comment: Yes, on non-Apple platforms `PUBLIC_HEADER` has no advantage over simple `install(FILES)`. As for `target_sources`, I find it useful only for `INTERFACE` targets. For normal libraries it is simpler to list its sources directly in `add_library` call.